# Changing options() in a function environment without changing options() in global environment in R?

Tags: r, function, global, environment

To suppress exponential notation for numerics, in my global environment I have `options("scipen" = 100)`. To do some stuff where i need exponential notation, I want to temporarily change this option inside of a function, like

```
f <- function(x){
                 options("scipen" = -100)
                 ...
}
```

However, changing the options inside a function automatically changes the options in the global environment as well. Is there a way to change options locally inside the function only?

Comment: Get the value at the time of the function call with `options("scipen")`, change the option, do the intended job in the function and when finished reset the value before the exit from the function.

Comment: Welcome to the “wonderful” world that is global values.

Comment: @nicola Very useful hint, can be most easily executed by Josh's suggestion, on.exit().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a good place to use `on.exit()`. It has the virtue of **ensuring** that the options get reset to their original values (stored in `oo`) before the evaluation frame of the function call is exited -- even if that exit is the result of an error.

```
f <- function(x) {
    oo <- options(scipen = -100)
    on.exit(options(oo))
    print(x)
}

## Try it out
1111
## [1] 1111
f(1111)
## [1] 1.111e+03
1111
## [1] 1111
```

Comment: Perfect, on.exit() is exactly what i was looking for. Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The withr package can do that:

```
library(withr)
f <- function(x) with_options(list(scipen = -100), {
          print(x)
})
f(1.2)
## [1] 1.2e+00
getOption("scipen")
## [1] 0
```